# comparing timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

HI, My php is very rusty and I can't quite remember how to do this.

I have a script that i only want to call every 15 minutes. I've created a table called last_updated. What I want to do is have some code at the top of my script that queries this last_updated table and if **now()** minus the last updated is greater than 15 minutes then run the script and also update last_updated to now...if it isn't don't run the script. Does this make sense?

Now I know when I'm updating last_updated I need to use now() To put a new timestamp in but I;m not sure how to do the comparing of now with the db value to see if it's greater then 15 mins.

Any ideas

Comment: "I've created a table [...] now() " - MySQL?

Comment: This shouldn't be initiated by a page load - what if no one visits the site in that 15 minute interval?  As in hours, or days...  Secondly, initiating from a page load will very likely have concurrency issues - what if two or more users load the page?  You need something to check that the value hasn't already been set.

Comment: It's not an issue if no-one has visited for more than 15 minutes. If a number of users hit the page at the same time then the script runs for the first of those visitors and checks the timestamp. If it's more than 15 minutes since the last update then do some stuff. The other users will trigger the same script but this time it will be less than 15 minutes since the last update so the update won't be carried out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=your_host;dbname=your_database', $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

// query the database. change 
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(last_updated_date) FROM last_updated ORDER BY last_updated_date DESC LIMIT 1');

$lastUpdatedTimestamp = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

if ((time() - $lastUpdatedTimestamp) > (60 * 15)) {
    touch($file);
    // do stuff
}
```

[time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives you the current time in seconds. You should probably unroll 60 * 15 to 900, I just provided it with both numbers to illustrate what was going on.

Also, a file might be better for this than a database table. Have a look at the [touch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php)
function. It changes the modification time of a file, or creates an empty file with the current time as the mod time if it doesn't exist. You can check the file mod time with [filemtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

```
<?php
$lastUpdated = null;
$file = '/path/to/writable/file/with/nothing/in/it';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    $lastUpdated = filemtime($lastUpdated);
}

if (!$lastUpdated || (time() - $lastUpdated) > 900) {
    touch($file);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks. I tried the touch file option but even though i've set privileges on the file and directories i'm still getting an error saying the touch file can't touch the file..so i've abandoned it as I don't really want to be setting too many write privileges for security reasons.

The timestamp example you gave....what is the $lastupdatedtimestamp? That's the bit i'm having problems with. If I have a table field with a datetime type and I'm inputting now() in to it that gives me something like: 2010-02-15 14:23:43...I need to convert it somehow to compare with time...

Comment: you could do it at the database level by wrapping the field in your query with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), or you could do it in your code by running the date value that comes out of the database with the php function strtotime(), which converts many different text dates to a unix timestamp.

Comment: i've updated my answer to explain where $lastUpdatedTimeStamp comes from - it's the value you pull out of your database. I don't know if you're using PDO or not, I can change the example if you aren't.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use MySQL as the DBMS. In that case and if you want you can let MySQL do most of the work:

```
SELECT
  pit < Now()-Interval 15 Minute as mustUpdate
FROM
  last_updated
WHERE
  siteId=?
```

`pit` is your DateTime field and `siteId` is some condition you may have if you store more than one record in the table (which sounds like a good idea to me).
The result (if there is such a record with `siteId=?`) contains a field `mustUpdate` which either contains `0` or `1`, 1 indicating that the value of pit is more than 15 minutes in the past.